# Why do I need a generic only when the constructor has a parameter

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

class MyList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_list: list[T] = []

class MyListWithX:
    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self.my_list: list[T] = []
```

The first class works fine, the second class throws the following error

```
main.py:11: error: Type variable "main.T" is unbound                                                   
main.py:11: note: (Hint: Use "Generic[T]" or "Protocol[T]" base class to bind "T" inside a class)  
main.py:11: note: (Hint: Use "T" in function signature to bind "T" inside a function)
```

It tells what how to fix it, that is **not** the question, my question is

**why do I need to use Generic only if my constructor has a parameter(self excluded)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that your constructor has a parameter, it's that it has a type annotation (which happens to be on your parameter).  By default, typechecking is only enabled on functions that have type annotations in their definition.  If you do:

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

class MyList:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.my_list: list[T] = []
```

you will see the error.

Comment: thanks @samwise, that makes sense, so I should be inheriting from Generic in that class as well? It wont let me accept your answer for some time

Comment: also, is there anyway I can "force" mypy to type check on functions that do not have an annotation in their definition but have annotations for other variables inside?

Comment: The TypeVar `T` has no meaning unless you inherit from `Generic[T]`, which is what allows you to say what `my_list` is a list of at the time you declare a `MyList`.

Comment: For handling untyped defs, see https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#untyped-definitions-and-calls.  I recommend using the `--disallow-untyped-defs` option.

Comment: @19029214 note `__init__` has different rules from other methods. See [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/class_basics.html?highlight=__init__#annotating-init-methods). You need `-> None` if and only if `__init__` has no parameters

Comment: It's not really unique to `__init__`, the same applies to any method that returns `None` and takes no annotated parameters.  It's just called out in the docs because `__init__` is the one people most commonly mess up on.  I always annotate every method's return type no matter what, even though `None` is implied when absent and there are other annotations, because it's easier to remember when you're in the habit of doing it every time.